# Eigen unaryExpr(): get index of element

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I know that in Eigen I can use `unaryExpr()` to apply a custom function to my Eigen Matrices and Vectors, e.g.

```
Eigen::VectorXd vec(4);
vec.unaryExpr([](double d) {
    return d * cos(d);
});
```

to apply custom functions to a `Eigen::VectorXd`. But is there also a way to get the position of the current element in my Vector? I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Eigen::VectorXd vec(4);
vec.unaryExpr([](double d, int index) {
     return index * d;
 });
```

which would for example multiply each entry in the vector by it's position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using a nullary expression as suggested by @ggael, you can also use a binary expression together with [`LinSpaced(size, 0, size-1)`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aaef589c1dbd7fad93f97bd3fa1b1e768):

```
VectorXd v; // some input vector

v = v.binaryExpr(VectorXd::LinSpaced(v.size(), 0, v.size()-1),
                 [](double d, double i){return d*i;});
// or much simpler and more efficient in this case:
v = v.cwiseProduct(VectorXd::LinSpaced(v.size(), 0, v.size()-1));
```

On sufficiently recent versions of Eigen, `LinSpaced` should get vectorized (although there are some border cases regarding the last element). `binaryExpr` only gets vectorized if the passed functor is vectorized, of course.

N.B.: If you are doing mostly element-wise operations, consider using `ArrayXd` instead of `VectorXd`.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround using a nullary expression:

```
VectorXd v;
v = VectorXd::NullaryExpr([&v](Index i) { return v(i)*i; });
```

You can do almost everything with a nullary expression: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html

Answer (score 0):

What you intend to do is nothing but an ordinary for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
   vec(i) *= i;
```

So why not keep things simple? If it's supposed to be usable for creating objects, wrap it in a helper function (template).

Besides, what you *can* do is relying on Eigen's internal order of evaluation. This seems to work, but I am unsure whether I would rely on it:

```
struct CountingUnaryFct {
   double operator()(double d) const { return d*index++; }
   mutable int index = 0;
};

vec.unaryExpr(CountingUnaryFct{});
```

This is a hack of considerable ugliness, as it tricks the `unaryExpr` template that requires its function object to have a `const`-qualified member `operator()(double) const` (not possible with a `mutable`-lambda, hence the function object) to accept an instance that actually does mutate its state under the hood. But again, it seems  to work reliably, at least on one-dimensional matrices.

Comment: I'd strongly advice against the second solution. While this likely works at the moment, there is no guarantee on the order in which coefficients are evaluated -- in the future this might very well happen in parallel, for example.